# How to run a project on a local computer?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Used by
  - Win 7x 64

I want to see how the project works with github.com - [project](https://github.com/syncfusion/syncfusion-ember).

**Question.**
How to make a project do this?

**I did:**
  1. Download the project to the folder.
`c:\test\visualStudio\JavaScript\01\`;
  2. Launched a shortcut:
`c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Node.js\Node.js command prompt.lnk`
The label contains the command:
`C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "C:\Program Files\nodejs\nodevars.bat"`

3. Entered the command: `npm install`
   [image]

What should I do next?

Comment: Using the command prompt, you have to change directory until you are located where you extracted the project. After this, you should be able to do `npm install`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be in the directory where the `package.json` is located. You can do this by going into your command prompt and typing the following, in this order:

1:

```
cd ../../
```

2:

```
cd test\visualStudio\JavaScript\01\
```

Once inside there, run `npm install`

Be mindful of spaces and backslashes.

Comment: I understood correctly ?:
 **1.** go to the directory where the project is unpacked;
 **2.** enter the command `npm install`;
 **3.** enter the command `ember build`;
 **4.** enter the command `ember serve`;
 **5.** go to browser (Google Chrome);
 **6.** Refresh page;